# Copy elision and move semantics not working as expected

Tags: c++, optimization

I made a program to assess the performance differences between doing this:

```
func3(func2(func1()));
```

vs this:

```
retval1 = func1();
retval2 = func2(retval1);
func3(retval2);
```

I prefer the latter for readability and ease of debugging, and I wanted to know if the compiler (MSVC 12.0) would optimize away the intermediate objects in a release build.  My test program is this:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

struct Indicator {
    Indicator() {cout << "Default constructor" << endl;}
    Indicator(const Indicator& other) {cout << "Copy constructor" << endl;}
    const Indicator& operator=(const Indicator& other) {cout << "Assignment operator" << endl;}
    ~Indicator() {cout << "Destructor" << endl;}
};

Indicator func1()
{return Indicator();}

Indicator func2(Indicator&& i)
{return std::move(i);}

Indicator func3(Indicator&& i)
{return std::move(i);}

int main() {
    Indicator i = func3(func2(func1()));
    cout << &i << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

I was surprised to see that even with -O2, there are still three instances of `Indicator` being created:

```
Default constructor
Copy constructor
Copy constructor
Destructor
Destructor
00000000002EFC70
Destructor
Press <RETURN> to close this window...
```

This conflicts with my understanding of move semantics, which is that there should only be one instance of `Indicator` created in this case.  I also thought that the compiler should be able to use NRVO for the chained function calls.  Can someone explain to me what's going on here?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Based on the [rule of 5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4782757/rule-of-three-becomes-rule-of-five-with-c11) when you defined your copy constructor and copy assignment operator, you disabled the compiler-generated move constructor and move assignment operator.

If you define your move constructor, you will get the output you expect.

```
Indicator(Indicator&& other) {cout << "Move constructor" << endl;}
Indicator& operator=(Indicator&& other) {cout << "Move assignment operator" << endl;}
```

[Working demo](http://cpp.sh/9gyia)

Comment: It is worth to note that Visual C++ 12 does not generate implicit move constructor at all.

Comment: Ahhh.  Yes, I see.  I just got used to adhering to the rule of 3, now I have to remember to define move constructors as well...

Comment: @Carlton Or stick to the rule of zero! If you don't **have to** define one (or some) of them, then let the compiler make them for you!